# How to create multiple Spark tasks to query Cassandra partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have an application that is using Spark (with Spark Job Server) that uses a Cassandra store. My current setup is that of a `client` mode running with `master=local[*]`. So there is a single Spark executor which is also the driver process that is using all 8 cores of the machine. I have a Cassandra instance running on the same machine.

The Cassandra tables have a primary key of the form ((datasource_id, date), clustering_col_1...clustering_col_n) where date is a single day of the form "2019-02-07" and is part of a composite partition key.

In my Spark application, I am running a query like so:

```
df.filter(col("date").isin(days: _*))
```

In the Spark physical plan, I notice that these filters along with the filter for the "datasource_id" partition key are pushed up to the Cassandra CQL query.

For our biggest datasources, I know that the partitions are around 30MB in size. So I have the following setting in the Spark Job Server configuration:

```
spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb = 1
```

However I notice that there is no parallelization in the Cassandra loading step. Though there are multiple Cassandra partitions that are >1MB, there are no additional spark partitions created. There is only a single task that does all the querying on a single core, thus taking ~20 secs to load data for a 1 month date range that corresponds to ~1 million rows.

I have tried the alternative approach below:

```
  df union days.foldLeft(df)((df: DataFrame, day: String) => {
    df.filter(col("date").equalTo(day))
  })
```

This does indeed create a spark partition (or task) for every "day" partition in cassandra. However, for smaller datasources where the cassandra partitions are much smaller in size, this method proves to be quite expensive in terms of excessive tasks created and the overhead due to their coordination. For these datasources, it would be totally fine to lump many cassandra partitions into one spark partition. Hence why I thought using the `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb` configuration would prove useful in dealing with both small and large datasources.

Is my understanding wrong? Is there something else that I'm missing in order for this configuration to take effect?

P.S. I have also read the answers about using joinWithCassandraTable. However, our code relies on using DataFrame. Also, converting from a CassandraRDD to a DataFrame is not very viable for us since our schema is dynamic and cannot be specified using case classes.